# JavaScript: Assign an unique identifier to an array and iterate over objects in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects

I have 4 arrays full of objects:

```
Array(16) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
Array(27) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
Array(21) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
Array(16) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
```

Each object contains a bit of information, that I want to display to the viewer:

`0: Object { exchange: "NYSE", quote: "JPY", price: "3923.76016", … }
​
1: Object { exchange: "DEF", quote: "GBP", price: "3924.60972", … }
​
2: Object { exchange: "FEG", quote: "EUR", price: "3917.31980", … }
​
3: {…}
​​
exchange: "NEX"
​​
price: "3914.70000"
​​
quote: "USD"
​​
timestamp: "2018-12-31T07:47:11.253Z"
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }`

How can I 
1) Assign a unique value to the array, ie. Array #1 is VTX, Array #2 is DEF, so that when I display it on the page, I don't need to change the ticker symbol (ie. VTX on exchange NEX is $100, and I only need to change the exchange name and currency/amount)

2) iterate over the arrays to where the iterator moves on to the next object in the array, let's say, every 2-3 seconds?

I'm doing this in React and have passed the data on to props, but now I'm stuck trying to figure this out.

Comment: 1) Assign the arrays to properties of an object: `{VTX: array1, DEF: array2, ...}`. 2) Keep a counter variable, `i`, increase it every 2-3 seconds and access `array[i]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can store all your arrays in on object like this :

```
const myArrays = [
    {
        uniqueName: 'VTX',
        infos: []
    },{
        uniqueName: 'DEF',
        infos: []
    }
]
```

2) You should store the index in the state, and make it change with setInterval in componentDidMount

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(
        () => this.nextInfo(),
        1000
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to assign the ID to my arrays to differentiate between quotes.  

For the second part, I'm still working it out...

Comment: Don't hesitate to upvote and accept the answer if it helped.